# What is the performing sequence of override methods on mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know overridden methods in performing sequence.

I researched with life cycle keywords but I haven't found anything significant.

Can anybody tell me what are them sequence:

- Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
- OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
- OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)

I have hierarchical order, and some pages have different authorization condition.

- All pages derived by CoreController
- Moderators page derived by ModeratorController (also derived by CoreController)
- Admin page derived by AdminController (also derived by CoreController)

I want to use override methods(one of the above or should use another?) in those controllers, but what is the sequence? I don't know that and want to learn.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence of invoking controller method is:

1. Initialize
2. OnAuthorization
3. OnActionExecuting

Comment: What's the source?
And do I have to call base method of its? Like "base.Initialize(requestContext);" and for others?

Comment: I just look to mvc source on http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1acb241299a8#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerActionInvoker.cs OnAuthorization/OnActionExecuting base are empty so you don't need but Initialize you should call